# Algorithm - How to distinguish 2 shapes of tray Opencv Python?

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I have 2 tray images, all I need to do is to detect whether tray is in forward direction,[This is forward direction of tray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGTd1.jpg) [This is reverse direction of tray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvqZm.jpg) [This is the template image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt2Sv.png)

First I cropped the source image and get the template image then I used "cv2.matchTemplate" algorithm to get the location of template in source image so [This is the result after using cv2.matchTemplate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Rc7.png) => this is what I want.

But the problem is the head of tray could be deformed like this
[This is deformed tray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rApNT.png) (due to operation of machine). If I decrease the threshold value to get both (not deformed and deformed head of tray) the program will also detect the reverse tray instead of forward tray [This is wrong detect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3xu4.png) so this is not what I want.

I'm stucking with this, any ideas? Should I change to another method or algorithm?, any helps would be greatly appreciated.

Code I used

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

main_image = cv2.imread('forwardtray.jpg')
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(main_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# open the template as gray scale image

template = cv2.imread('tray.png', 0)
width, height = template.shape[::-1] #get the width and height
# match the template using cv2.matchTemplate
match = cv2.matchTemplate(gray_image, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

threshold = 0.35
position = np.where(match >= threshold) # get the location of template in the image
# draw the rectangle around the matched template
for point in zip(*position[::-1]): 
cv2.rectangle(main_image, point, (point[0] + width, point[1] + height), (0, 204, 153), 0)
cv2.imshow('Template Found', main_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Templatematching is not a good approach when you have different perspectives such that the images would not align well from just a translation. Perhaps you should consider feature matching.

Comment: @fmw42 I did looked up for feature matching but the official docs said that the algorithms in feature matching ( SIFT, SURF) has been removed from opencv due to patent matter so there is no way to get it. :(

Comment: It is in a contributed library. But you can also use other methods such as ORB, for example, I believe. See for example, https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html and https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d27/tutorial_py_table_of_contents_feature2d.html

Comment: Seconding fmw42's suggestion.